# Postgresql is not avaible in Libreoffice Base

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, postgresql, libreoffice-base

I want to edit a postgresql base using libreoffice-base.

When I launch the database wizard of Libreoffice-base, I am blocked at the first step: I can select an existing base, but the only ones available are:

- jdbc
- oracle jdbc
- spreadsheet
- dbase
- text
- mysql
- obbc

The list does not include postgresql. My libreoffice version is 3.5.4.2, and my OS is Ubuntu 12.04.

What packages should I install so as to have postgresql in this list ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I've found out what was wrong...

I only had to install the package `libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql` , and now I can select postgresql in libreoffice-base.